# Combine tables with SQL where columns are dynamic

Tags: sql, sqlite, automation

We have separate pages for maintaining some Project metrics. Few metrics are common but some are applicable only for specific project. Using Python with Selenium and SQLite. Have written code to fetch data from specific page and store in a runtime SQL table.

Sample data and expected result
Project_A:

| Project_Name | Month | Metric1 | Metric2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Jan-21 | 12 | 5 |
| A | Feb-21 | 15 | 10 |

Project_B:

| Project_Name | Month | Metric1 | Metric3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | Jan-21 | 05 | 5 |
| B | Feb-21 | 20 | 10 |

Want to create one master table which will contain all the projects with their metrics. I can use a union, a query like below and combine the data from different table.

```
SELECT Project_Name , Metric1, Metric2, Null as Metric3 FROM Project_A
Union 
Select Project_Name , Metric1, Null as Metric2, Metric3 FROM Project_B
```

Combined Result:

| Project_Name | Month | Metric1 | Metric2 | Metric3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Jan-21 | 12 | 5 |  |
| A | Feb-21 | 15 | 10 |  |
| B | Jan-21 | 05 |  | 5 |
| B | Feb-21 | 20 |  | 10 |

**Challenge is**: Looking if any option is there were, we can combine tables without mentioning the column names.

Answer (score 1):

It's suggested to not have a column for each Metric Type/Measure, nor a table per project measurements.  Instead, have a details table with a row for each metric reading, and a column indicating the type of metric, plus a column referring to the project.

Some of the detail may be stored in other tables, like a unique list of valid metric types (one row per type) and a table containing the unique list of projects (one row per project), etc.

The form of the table containing the measurements might look like this first CTE term:

```sql
WITH Measurements (Project_Name, Month, Metric_Type, Metric) AS (
         SELECT 'A', 'Jan-21', 'Metric1', 12 UNION
         SELECT 'A', 'Jan-21', 'Metric2',  5 UNION
         SELECT 'A', 'Feb-21', 'Metric1', 12 UNION
         SELECT 'A', 'Feb-21', 'Metric2', 10 UNION
         SELECT 'B', 'Jan-21', 'Metric1', 05 UNION
         SELECT 'B', 'Jan-21', 'Metric3',  5 UNION
         SELECT 'B', 'Feb-21', 'Metric1', 20 UNION
         SELECT 'B', 'Feb-21', 'Metric3', 10
     )
SELECT * FROM Measurements
;
```

Result:

| Project_Name | Month | Metric_Type | Metric |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Feb-21 | Metric1 | 12 |
| A | Feb-21 | Metric2 | 10 |
| A | Jan-21 | Metric1 | 12 |
| A | Jan-21 | Metric2 | 5 |
| B | Feb-21 | Metric1 | 20 |
| B | Feb-21 | Metric3 | 10 |
| B | Jan-21 | Metric1 | 5 |
| B | Jan-21 | Metric3 | 5 |

Comment: This is a valid approach and thanks for sharing this. However in my case I will be using this combined data as input for Power BI to generate a dashboard, that was the reason trying to keep different metric as header.

Comment: @Kumar You could still generate that "column per type" result from the above, in several ways.  For example, a view could be created which produces the "column per type" result.

Comment: @Kumar This avoids the need to use different column names per type, allowing filtering based on a list of types against the common Metric_Type column.